# Getting ERROR in React JS: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data?

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, api, firebase-realtime-database

We are working on Firebase and we want to fetch the firebase data in our react js UI. We have created API for fetching the data in Flask. The flask code is given below

```
firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config) db = firebase.database()

# Receive data from Firebase RealTime Database @app.route("/") def home():
    db_events = db.child().get().val()
    return jsonify(db_events)
```

Now, the API is called in React JS component, the code is given below:-

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Temperature from './components/temperature';

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    contacts: [],
    temperatures: [],
  };

  componentDidMount(){
    fetch('192.168.1.2:5000')
      .then( res => res.json() )
      .then( (data) => {
        this.setState({ contacts: data })
        console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(console.log)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div></div>
    );
  }

}

export default App;
```

But, when we start the server, we got error in console. The error is given below:

> SyntaxError: "JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data"

The JSON we are getting from the APIs is given below:

```
{
    "DHT11": {
        "Humidity": {
            "-LuWFvEpzI9QAu_8eMEr": "49.00%",
            "-LuWHg8WL90DOdkSKd5J": "48.00%",
            "-LuWHmHpZ2veEKk1qqx2": "49.00%",
            "-LuWHpUA9l-W6_ZBUV9W": "49.00%"
        },
        "LED_STATUS": "OFF",
        "Temperature": {
            "-LuWFvMVeyUhfKEpCxqe": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHgGX-tepMSXLRZiJ": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHmPdHdgBaQxkSbh4": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHpb-d4UbkomxayjN": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHsnQqIeUm1QGtixw": "23.00°C"
       }
    }
}
```

Why we are getting this error, all the other dummy APIs are working here. When we checked the format of JSON, it is valid. What we are getting from the error is the keys in our JSON format are not supporting.

Please help us to solve the issue. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are logging the data and it is working. That means the problem is elsewhere in your code. Show us the react component you are using the render the data. You can remove the flask code. If the data is logging correctly then it is irrelevant to this question.

Comment: @JoshPittman All the other APIs are working. But this one which we have created with Flask is not working. The JSON is correct.

Comment: @JoshPittman I have updated the Component Code.

Comment: If you are saying the data is logging to console correctly then there is nothing wrong with you api. Try removing the fetch call 'componentDidMount', do you still get the error?

Answer (score 0):

Your `Temperature` object is missing an ending brace...
Also `JSON.parse` fails for trailing commas...
See the corrected JSON below...

```
{
    "DHT11": {
        "Humidity": {
            "-LuWFvEpzI9QAu_8eMEr": "49.00%",
            "-LuWHg8WL90DOdkSKd5J": "48.00%",
            "-LuWHmHpZ2veEKk1qqx2": "49.00%",
            "-LuWHpUA9l-W6_ZBUV9W": "49.00%"
        },
        "LED_STATUS": "OFF",
        "Temperature": {
            "-LuWFvMVeyUhfKEpCxqe": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHgGX-tepMSXLRZiJ": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHmPdHdgBaQxkSbh4": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHpb-d4UbkomxayjN": "23.00°C",
            "-LuWHsnQqIeUm1QGtixw": "23.00°C"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can we remove the trailing commas from our JSON? The data is coming in real time from our sensors to the firebase database. Your Temperature object is missing an ending brace... this is done by mistake. we have correted it.

Comment: This is not the limiting data, we have more. This data updated in real time.

Comment: Kwame Opare Asiedu There are no trailing commas in JSON format, the JSON is valid. We have checked it.

Comment: Ohk... Is your API giving you the exact snippet you posted or you are getting a JSON string...??